# Apache redirecting when it shouldnt

Tags: linux, redirect, apache-2.2

I have inherited a LAMP server with a lot of customization.

I want to enable mod_status in apache to get some monitoring of apache started. 
Problem is, with mod_status enabled in the httpd.conf, I am not allowed to travel to the http://"serverIP"/server-status URL because apache is redirecting me to a 'landing page'.

If I type any invalid URL for the server, it redirects to this page, all error document pages have been hashed out from the httpd.conf.

Any assistance to where this has may have been configured or if there is a way to override it so I can get to the url http://"serverIP"/server-status ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up a `<Location /server-status>` inside your `<VirtualHost>` with the `SetHandler server-status` directive set?

Comment: yes, it does not make a difference.

Comment: @IvanMoldavi Are you sure that it's that `<VirtualHost>` that's serving the request?  Or can you provide your Apache configuration?

Comment: Apparently it's the base config / outside of VirtualHost. See your default virtual host and/or rewrite configuration. The default virtual host should also have the /server-status entry.